# CocoaPods No such file or directory

Tags: objective-c, ruby, swift, cocoapods

I just installed CocoaPods and cannot seem to run any commands.

All the follow commands give the same error:

```
$ pod init
$ pod setup
$ pod install
```

Error:

```
 -bash: /Users/emma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/pod: No such file or directory
```

Comment: How have you installed CocoaPods? Looks like you've done it incorrectly.

Comment: Open Terminal and navigate to the directory containing your project by using the cd command:

`cd ~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/yourProject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way to install Cocoapods is with the following `Terminal` commands (in this order):

```
sudo gem update --system

sudo gem install cocoapods

pod setup

cd ~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/YourApp

pod init
```

After `pod init` you should be able to open and edit the podfile

```
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

And add your pod to it (f.e.:)

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.2.1'
```

to install the added pods run command `pod install`

After the installation of the pods, use `*.xcworkspace` instead of `*.xcodeproj`

A clear tutorial can be found on the good 'ol [RayWenderlich website](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2).